# Unable to connect to remote Cassandra Cluster using Datastax PHP Driver

Tags: php, cassandra, datastax-php-driver

I am currently involved in creating an API that uses a Cassandra cluster with 3 nodes for storing data. I was developing it on my local machine using PHP 5.6.17, Cassandra 2.2.3 and the Datastax PHP Driver 1.1.0 and everything went fine.

However, we decided to move to a remote Cassandra cluster (3.4 with native protocol 4) and I cannot access it through PHP as I get the following error: **An error occured: 16777226 - No hosts available for the control connection**.

The funny thing is that using the remote cluster's ip and using the DevCenter, I managed to connect to that cluster, create a new keyspace (SimpleStrategy, RF:2), create a new table and add one row of data.

The error producing PHP code is the following:

`$cluster   = \Cassandra::cluster()
              ->withContactPoints('x.x.x.x')
              ->build();
$keyspace  = 'foo';
$session   = $cluster->connect($keyspace);`

The last line is the one producing the error. However, if I try to connect to the local cassandra cluster using `$cluster   = \Cassandra::cluster()->build();` then it works like a charm.
Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I found that the [official php driver](https://github.com/datastax/php-driver) for Cassandra does not support Cassandra 3.x. I will try and find if somebody has forked this repo and tried to fix it. It will be much appreciated if somebody knows more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try these solution

Add "->withPort(port_number)" default is 9042
OR 
Check firewall is blocking access in your host machine